# Can I set Other Swift flags in code?

Tags: ios

I would like to set a debug/release switcher in app. Can I set Other Swift flags in code?

```
#if DEBUG
....
#else
....
#endif
```

Comment: you want to have some different settings of something for testing and release versios like urls right ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

Well for that purposes you will need to add multiple targets to your project. [Here](http://samwize.com/2014/05/22/create-multiple-targets-slash-apps-for-1-xcode-project/) is  atutorial for that. And  when you are done adding targets then you can check like this

```
    #if DEV // Develeopent target
        // testing enviourment settings
    #elseif QA // QA target
        // QA enviourment settings
    #else
        // Live enviourment settings
    #endif
```

Comment: They represent your targets and you can not add or remove them using code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add **-DDEBUG** and **-DRELEASE** to **Debug** and **Release** Other Swift Flags

Comment: yeah I've set that, but I would like to know if I can set it in code :)